# Unable to setup lsp-mode with lsp-pyright

Tags: python, lsp-mode, lsp

I'm using Emacs 28.1 on macOS 11.6.6 (installed with `brew`) and want to setup a Python IDE with [`lsp-mode`](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode) and [`lsp-pyright`](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-pyright).
My (not full) `init.el` looks like this (LSP and Python setups are at the bottom of the file):

```
;; Define and load custom.el file
(setq custom-file (expand-file-name "custom.el" user-emacs-directory))
(when (file-exists-p custom-file)
  (load custom-file))

;; Modify package repositories
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)

;; Load and activate Emacs packages
(package-initialize)

;; Install use-package if it's not installed
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))

;; Load use-package
(require 'use-package)
(setq use-package-hook-name-suffix nil) ;; Do not append text to the name of hooks mentioned by :hook

;; Load use-package-ensure
;; Support for :ensure and :pin keywords in use-package declarations
(require 'use-package-ensure)
(setq use-package-always-ensure t)

;; exec-path-from-shell
(use-package exec-path-from-shell
  :ensure t
  :if (eq system-type 'darwin)
  :custom
  (exec-path-from-shell-variables
   '("PATH" "MANPATH" "XDG_CONFIG_HOME" "WORKON_HOME" "LSP_USE_PLISTS" "PYTHONPATH" "IPYTHONDIR" "MPLCONFIGDIR"))
  (exec-path-from-shell-arguments nil)
  :config
  ;; (setenv "PKG_CONFIG_PATH" "/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))

;; Helm
;; Input completion
(use-package helm
  :ensure t
  :init
  (helm-mode 1)
  (require 'helm-config)
  :bind
  ;; ("C-c i"   . helm-imenu) ;; Select document heading
  ("C-x b"   . helm-mini) ;; Select buffers
  ("C-x C-f" . helm-find-files) ;; Open or create files
  ("C-x C-r" . helm-recentf) ;; Select recently saved files
  ("M-x"     . helm-M-x) ;; Evaluate functions
  ("M-y"     . helm-show-kill-ring) ;; Show the kill ring
  (:map helm-map
    ("<tab>" . helm-execute-persistent-action)
    ("C-z" . helm-select-action)))

;; which-key
;; Input completion
(use-package which-key
  :ensure t
  :custom
  (which-key-idle-delay 0.5)
  (which-key-idle-secondary-delay 0.5)
  :config
  (which-key-mode 1)
  (which-key-setup-side-window-bottom))

;; Company
;; Text completion
(use-package company
  :ensure t
  :custom
  (company-idle-delay 0.0)
  (company-minimum-prefix-length 4)
  (company-selection-wrap-around t)
  :hook
  ((text-mode-hook . company-mode)
   (prog-mode-hook . company-mode))
  :bind
  (:map company-active-map
    ("<tab>" . nil)
    ("TAB" . nil)
    ("M-<tab>" . company-complete-common-or-cycle)
    ("M-<tab>" . company-complete-selection)))

;; Flyspell
;; Spell checking for text (requires aspell)
(use-package flyspell
  :ensure t
  :init
  (setq ispell-program-name "aspell")
  :hook
  ((text-mode-hook . flyspell-mode)
   (prog-mode-hook . flyspell-prog-mode))
  :bind
  ("<f7>" . flyspell-word)
  ("M-<f7>" . flyspell-buffer))

;; Flycheck
;; Spell checking for code
(use-package flycheck
  :ensure t
  :init
  (setq flycheck-highlighting-mode 'symbols
    flycheck-indication-mode 'left-fringe
    flycheck-standard-error-navigation t)
  :hook
  (prog-mode-hook . flycheck-mode))

;; LSP Mode
;; Language Server Protocol Support
(use-package lsp-mode
  :ensure t
  :hook
  (lsp-mode-hook . lsp-enable-which-key-integration)
  :bind
  ("s-l" . lsp-keymap-prefix)
  :commands lsp)

(use-package lsp-ui
  :ensure t
  :after lsp-mode
  :hook
  (lsp-mode-hook . lsp-ui-mode)
  :bind
  (:map lsp-ui-mode-map
    ("C-c i" . lsp-ui-menu)))

(use-package lsp-pyright
  :ensure t
  :after (python lsp-mode)
  :custom
  (lsp-pyright-venv-path (getenv "WORKON_HOME"))
  :hook
  (python-mode-hook . (lambda ()
            (require 'lsp-pyright) (lsp))))

;; Python
(use-package python
  :ensure t
  :custom
  ;; (python-shell-completion-native-enable nil)
  (python-indent-guess-indent-offset-verbose nil)
  (python-shell-buffer-name "IPython")
  (python-shell-interpreter "ipython")
  (python-shell-interpreter-args "-i --simple-prompt")
  :hook
  ((python-mode-hook . flyspell-prog-mode)
   (python-mode-hook . flycheck-mode)
   (python-mode-hook . company-mode)
   (python-mode-hook . lsp)))

;; pyenv-mode
;; Integrate pyenv with python-mode
(use-package pyenv-mode
  :ensure t
  :if (eq system-type 'darwin)
  :after python
  :hook
  (python-mode-hook . pyenv-mode))

;; pyvenv
;; Python virtual environment support
(use-package pyvenv
  :ensure t
  :after python
  :custom
  (pyvenv-workon "env")
  :hook
  ((python-mode-hook . pyvenv-mode)
   (pyvenv-post-activate-hooks . pyvenv-restart-python)
   (pyvenv-post-deactivate-hooks . pyvenv-restart-python))
  :config
  (defalias 'workon 'pyvenv-workon)
  (defalias 'deactivate 'pyvenv-deactivate))

;;; init.el ends here
```

Basically, I use `pyenv` to manage different Python versions on my machine.
I also manage virtual environments under `WORKON_HOME`, which is defined in my `.profile` file as `~/.python/venv`.
Generally, I use just a single venv called `env` for all my scripting purposes.

My goal is to use LSP for Python whenever I open a `.py` file.

According to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright#emacs), `lsp-mode` and `lsp-pyright` are the only necessary parts to run LSP for Python in Emacs.

Now, in my current setup, whenever I run Emacs (from Applications) and open a `.py` file, I get this in my minibuffer:

```
Unable to find installed server supporting this file. The following servers could be installed automatically:
```

The only possible choice I have is `pyright` (it seems that it doesn't find `lsp-pyright`).
I choose it, press `Enter` and get the following message in `*Messages*` buffer:

```
LSP :: Download pyright started.
LSP :: Server pyright install process failed with the following error message: Unable to find a way to install pyright.
Check `*lsp-install*' and `*lsp-log*' buffer.
```

The `*lsp-log*` looks like this:

```
Command "pyls" is not present on the path.
Command "pylsp" is not present on the path.
Unable to install pyright via `npm' because it is not present
```

<s>Why is it not finding my `lsp-pyright` installation?</s>
Perhaps I am missing something on Python's side (some packages, etc.)?

Sidenotes:

1. I use `(setq use-package-hook-name-suffix nil)` so all of my `:hook`
   definitions involve `-hook(s)` at the end.
2. As I understand, `pyls` (also know as [python-language-server](https://github.com/palantir/python-language-server)) is [deprecated](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-pyls/).

---

UPDATE:

All I needed to do to solve this problem was to install the actual language server for Python.
I did this by using `brew`, as `pyright` is available there:

```
brew install pyright
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your config, and it works for me. You can see the below figure. I faced an issue in using `helm`, so I disabled only the `use-package` declaration.

[image]

The relevant error is "npm because it is not present", which is what is used by `lsp-mode` or `lsp-install-sever` to install many language servers, including `pyright`. You can use the following link to install `npm` on your preferred OS (I am assuming Ubuntu).

[How to Install Node.js and npm on Ubuntu 20.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04/)

Note that you can also install `pyright` by yourself globally so that it is available in your `$PATH`. Then, `lsp-mode` clients will no longer try to install the server on your behalf. You can do either of the following:

```
npm install -g pyright 
# If you prefer snap: https://snapcraft.io/
sudo snap install pyright --classic
```

Comment: Oh, so this clears things up a bit as I was actually missing something (the `npm` part). For me personally, various documentations I read were very unclear as to what I actually need in order make this setup work (I have never heard about `npm` up until today). Anyway, thanks for clearing this up!

Comment: Nice. You may want to accept and upvote the answer.